# Encoding string data back to JSON is giving an error

Tags: swift

I've removed `jsonCallback (` and `)` from the URL https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/data/developer/system_status_en_US.js using the below.

```
        var dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        dataString = dataString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "jsonCallback(", with: "")
        dataString = dataString?.replacingOccurrences(of: ");", with: "")
        let json = dataString?.data(using: .utf8)
        let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(json)
```

The error I'm getting back

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

I can't find where the mismatch is happening at because when I look at `dataString` and piece it back together the JSON decoding model appears to match.

Here's the full code:

```
 func fetchSystemStatus() async -> [SystemStatus] {
        guard let url = URL(string: systemStatusURL) else {
            return []
        }

        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

            // This is commented out data to try and gather developer system status
            var dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            dataString = dataString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "jsonCallback(", with: "")
            dataString = dataString?.replacingOccurrences(of: ");", with: "")
            let json = dataString?.data(using: .utf8)
            let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(json)

            guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else {
                print("\(#function) \(response)")
                return []
            }

            let statusData = try JSONDecoder().decode(SystemStatus.self, from: jsonData)
            return [statusData]
        } catch {
            print("\(#function) \(error)")
            return []
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
// MARK: - SystemStatus
struct SystemStatus: Codable {
    let services: [Service]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case services = "services"
    }
}

// MARK: - Service
struct Service: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let redirectURL: String?
    let events: [Event]
    let serviceName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case redirectURL = "redirectUrl"
        case events = "events"
        case serviceName = "serviceName"
    }
}

// MARK: - Event
struct Event: Codable {
    let usersAffected: String
    let epochStartDate: Int
    let epochEndDate: Int
    let messageID: String
    let statusType: String
    let datePosted: String
    let startDate: String
    let endDate: String
    let affectedServices: [String]?
    let eventStatus: String
    let message: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case usersAffected = "usersAffected"
        case epochStartDate = "epochStartDate"
        case epochEndDate = "epochEndDate"
        case messageID = "messageId"
        case statusType = "statusType"
        case datePosted = "datePosted"
        case startDate = "startDate"
        case endDate = "endDate"
        case affectedServices = "affectedServices"
        case eventStatus = "eventStatus"
        case message = "message"
    }
}
```

Comment: On which iOS version are you testing? Also `let jsonData = Data(dataString.utf8)` should do the trick, no need for additional conversions (with `JSONEncoder`)...

Comment: @Sh_Khan I added the mode.

Comment: @Larme it's iOS 15

Comment: `try JSONDecoder().decode(SystemStatus.self, from: Data(json!))` works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
let statusData = try JSONDecoder().decode(SystemStatus.self, from: Data(json!))
```

or

```
let statusData = try JSONDecoder().decode(SystemStatus.self, from: Data(dataString!.utf8))
```

What's your issue:

```
let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(json)
```

But `json` here is `Data`, so if you call `JSONEncoder` on it, by default, it will use Base64, so it won't be like the JSON you expect.
But `json` already is correct.

Comment: Thank you! This did it.  I initially tried using `json`, but failed to use `Data()`